# JNI byteArray passing help

Tags: c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have been running into issues with my Android app closing (no errors or anything) when trying to execute the following code:

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_teamjeff_oggstreamtest_MainTest_audioFunc(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
//<REMOVED VARIABLE INITIALIZATION>
  jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
  jmethodID writeDataFunc = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "writeToAudioTrack", "([B)V");
  if (!writeDataFunc) return;
  jmethodID readDataFunc = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "readFromBuffer", "([B)I");
  if (!readDataFunc) return;

  rawDataRead = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, 4096);
  bytes = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, obj,readDataFunc, &rawDataRead);
  char* carr = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, rawDataRead, NULL);
  memcpy(buffer, carr, bytes);
  (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, rawDataRead);
//<REMOVED REST OF FUNCTION>
}
```

I've tracked the "trouble" code to the `bytes = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, obj,readDataFunc, &rawDataRead);` line. If I return before this line, my app doesn't close, but if I return immediately after this line, my app closes randomly without even an error.

Here is the JAVA code:

```
package teamjeff.oggstreamtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import com.Ostermiller.util.CircularByteBuffer;


public class MainTest extends Activity {

    public static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private final CircularByteBuffer cbb = new CircularByteBuffer(1024*512, true);
    public AudioTrack mAudioTrack;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("vorbis-decoder");
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {

            final Socket test = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(<HOME SERVER URL>), <PORT>);

            new Thread(
                    new Runnable(){
                      public void run(){
                          try {
                                 while(!test.isClosed()) {
                                     byte[] temp = new byte[4096];
                                     int bytes = test.getInputStream().read(temp, 0, 4096);
                                     cbb.getOutputStream().write(temp, 0, bytes);
                                 }
                              } catch (Exception e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                              }
                      }
                    }
                  ).start();


            mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    44100,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    1024*64,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            mAudioTrack.play();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    audioFunc();
                }
            }).start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public native void audioFunc();

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void writeToAudioTrack(final byte[] media) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mAudioTrack.write(media, 0, media.length);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int readFromBuffer(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            return cbb.getInputStream().read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

I have searched for days here and on Google on how to accomplish what I want to do. My code above is the gluing together of various code snippets I've found around the internet with tweaks to fit my use-case.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

I will read in data from a socket in my Android App, pass this data to my C code for decoding (though the algorithm reads it in piece by piece during the algorithm, meaning I can't pass in the byteArray from Java to C and call my C function multiple times since the decoder sometimes uses data from previous read-in bytes). My C code does the decoding, and passes the PCM data back to my Android app to be played on an AudioTrack.

I am using a circular buffer to buffer in the data from the socket.

When I try to debug my Android App, I set break points at the entries to both the read and write functions and they never seem to be called.

Am I doing something wrong when I pass the byteArray from my C code to JAVA to be filled with data? Should I be doing this an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes that might help.

1. &rawDataRead is wrong. Lose the &. You just pass the ref that you get, not the address of it.
2. you don't need to delete that local ref. All local refs are deleted when a native function returns. I'm fairly confident that this is true in *java*, but the android situation may be different.
3. You don't have to keep retrieving the method ids. You can get them once and hang onto them.

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed my error! However, my application continued to crash when I removed the DeleteLocalRef() calls after a few seconds of running. When I put them back i get about 2-3 minutes of playback before I hit some kind of 24MB max memory limit. Is there a way to further free memory during the execution of my program? I don't know why these byte arrays aren't being freed by the GC after I delete the local reference!

Comment: @som I think I could quote you chapter and verse on this for *java*. Which leads me to think that you're experiencing something specific to android, which I can't help you with.

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out I was running out of memory by queuing threads of data to write to the AudioTrack that wasn't depleting faster than the decoder was decoding (something I was not expecting given my other decoding tests with other libraries I used). I added some thread control on the JAVA side to block the thread queuing to a reasonable amount. Thanks again for all your help!